# How to navigate Yahoo Finance pages using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, finance, yahoo-finance

I am currently using requests, BeautifulSoup, and the lxml parser to read and pull web content from Yahoo Finance. Is there any way I can call the request function using the home page of a company, and then make python navigate through the rest of the tabs for that company?

For example, I'm using Airbnb in this case, if I pass the following page: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ABNB?p=ABNB can I make my code navigate to the financials tab of the page and then pull data from there? What would the code for that look like? I have thought about using a for loop using page numbers but Yahoo Finance doesn't seem to have that.

Comment: If you are considering getting financial statements, you might want to consider implementing [yahoo_fin](http://theautomatic.net/yahoo_fin-documentation/) and [yanooquery](https://yahooquery.dpguthrie.com/).

Comment: What's the command for accessing balance sheet/income statement data using these packages? The yahoo_fin one doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: [https://yahooquery.dpguthrie.com/alternative/](https://yahooquery.dpguthrie.com/alternative/) Kindly refer to this.I also tried to run the code here. yfinance didn't get it, but yahooquery did.